# Polling for a atomic variable (bool) in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdatomic

I have a thread which modifies one atomic variable (bool) and another thread which wants to poll that variable. My application makes few function calls in `thread A` and start polling on one specific atomic variable. `Thread B` keeps on reading the status of some external application (`application on dbus`) and modifies few atomic variable accordingly. A function in `Thread A` wants to make sure that if it returns, then some external application has changed it's state to desired state which it will get to know via these atomic flags.

**Details of my application:**

The function in `thread A` is `start_scan()` function which starts scanning nearby BLE devices using `dbus API`. However, even if `start scan` call was successful but external application (`org.bluez`) still takes some time to update it's properties (`Property: Discovering`). I have also defined functions like `isScanning` which queries some variables (internal to my application) for current status of external application. Whenever, external application's properties are updated, it notifies other application via `PropertiesChanged` signal over `dbus` and yes, it takes some time (less than a second) before i receive `PropertiesChanged` signal for scanning after successful call to `start_scan`. So, I am thinking to poll for my local atomic flags (with my own timeout mechanism) before i return from `start_scan` function, This will make sure if someone queries status of scanning after calling `start_scan`, then `isScanning` will return a valid state.

I can't use condition_variable as I have many functions and flags which needs to be in syn.

**Problem:**

```
std::atomic<bool> scanning_;

// Thread A
void start_scan()
{
    // Dbus methods call
    while (scanning_ == false) { // With some timeout
        // Timeout mechanism
    }
}

// Thread B receving asyn signals from DBus
void propertyUpdate(std::string name, bool value)
{
    if (name == "Discovering")
        scanning_ = value;

    ...
}
```

When thread A will be polling for `scanning_` flag, thread B will receive `dbus` signal to update `scanning_` flag. I am not sure if `Thread A` will choke thread B as if it will be continuously reading the flag and my flag is atomic? I want to know how thread waiting for atomic variables access are scheduled if atomic variable becomes available?

**EDIT:**

I am doing something like this:

```
    void setter(bool value)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex lock(mutex_);
        member_ = value;
    }

    bool getter(void)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex lock(mutex_);
        return member_;
    }

    // Thread A is blocking on a class member value
    while (getter() == false);

    // Thread B will modify the class member when required
    setter(true);
```

I want to know the possible problem I can face because of scheduling of blocked threads on a common mutex. Is it possible that thread A will keep on acquiring mutex_ while thread B will be blocked forever. It could occur if thread B is not scheduled after `getter` function in thread A returns and before thread A acquires mutex_ again.

Comment: Couldn't you use a mutex or semaphore?

Comment: Polling is a waste of resources and the standard doesn't guarantee it will ever work. Use condition variables.

Comment: @n.m.: Do you mean my thread wouldn't see the update if my thread polls on a variable which is modified by other thread?

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: If a thread is polling, there's no guarantee any other thread will ever have a chance to run..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to block a thread until a condition becomes true (in your case, `scanning_` with a timeout), then you should use [condition variables](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable). This way, `scanning_` would be just a normal variable, not an atomic one, and it will be protected by a mutex.

(Using atomic variables for some thread communication is possible, but you cannot make a thread sleep with just using atomic variables. In your example, start_scan constantly runs, eats CPU time)

Comment: Yes but I have several variable for polling and I don't want to create a conditional variable for each flag.

Comment: Currently, I don't have time to read your updated post, I just respond to your comment. You don't need to create multiple condvars. When **any** of the flags changes, you should call condvar.signal(). Then, in the other thread, after condvar.wait() returns, you can check the value of the flags. Sorry If you cannot use this method, I'll read your post at a later time.

Comment: What is the exact cause that you cannot use condvar? As I written in my previous comment, you can use whatever conditions you need. You can do as complex expressions as you want to wait for. In the **EDIT**, you still have the `while(getter()==false)`, which is causes 100% usage for that thread.